# How do I create a regular expression to match a word misspelling the original case sensitivity?

Tags: regex

I want to discover wrong spelling of "FooBar" in sentence:

"This is a 'FooBar' example where I should match different spelling of fooBar such as:
foobar, FOOBAR or even fOoBaR but not foobarS!"

In this sentence, I would like to match words (in order):
fooBar, foobar, FOOBAR, fOoBaR
and not:
FooBar (correct spelling), foobarS (not the same word)

Is there an existing solution using Perl Regular Expression? This is intended to be used with grep -P

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "$str" | grep -P '\b(?!FooBar)(?i:foobar)\b'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=^|\W)(?!FooBar)(?i)foobar(?=\W|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

cat foobar.txt | grep -P '(?!FooBar)[fF][oO][oO][bB][aA][rR]'

Comment: Not generic enough, see accepted answer, thanks anyway for your help!